# Missing Widgets

Tags: python, data-mining, orange

I have recently installed Orange Data Mining tool, but cannot seem to find a few widgets such as "Scatter Plot" and "Distributions". I'm currently using version 3.3.8.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Please show your work. What have you tried?

Comment: You mean on Orange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install Orange? Seems like there's an issue with your PyQt installation. I'd suggest going Conda ([Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution), as it works out of the box (at least on Windows).

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install orange3
```

Comment: I used pip rather than conda, as instructed in the README.md on github.

Comment: I'm no expert here, but I'd re-install PyQt4 (remove from site-packages and install it again (wheel, brew, apt-get, choose your drug)).

But still, I prefer pure Anaconda, it makes everything easier. A PR with conda installation instructions is already on the repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. Installed Anaconda and did as you instructed. Much appreciate :)